# IE8 long running script error when using DataTables

Tags: javascript, performance

I have an application that uses the DataTables jQuery library to render content in my target browser IE8.  The problem is when I push a big array to be rendered, IE8 sometimes throws up the infamous long running script error.

After profiling the app it seems that the call to __fnAddData in the following code is causing the problem:

```
if (bUsePassedData) {
  for (var i = 0, len = oInit.aaData.length; i < len; i++) {
      _fnAddData(oSettings, oInit.aaData[i]);
  }
} else if (oSettings.bDeferLoading ||
               (oSettings.sAjaxSource === null && oSettings.ajax === null)) {
  _fnAddTr(oSettings, $(oSettings.nTBody).children('tr'));
}
```

I was looking around for solutions and saw Nicholas Zakas' write up [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/) and tons of other solutions that would work if the for loop wasn't inside of an if else if "block".  When I tried, on my 1st attempt of many, to wrap it in a setTimeout function it of course didn't work because the 2nd part of the if else if resolves to true.

```
(oSettings.sAjaxSource === null && oSettings.ajax === null) // true
```

What is a good solution for this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might split up your function in 3 functions:

1. Before the if statement.
2. Processing the oInit.aaData
3. After the if statement

Here is the code split up in 3 functions:

```
function beforeIf(){
     if (bUsePassedData) {
       procesData(oSettings,oInit.aaData.concat());
     } else if (oSettings.bDeferLoading ||
                   (oSettings.sAjaxSource === null && oSettings.ajax === null)) {
       _fnAddTr(oSettings, $(oSettings.nTBody).children('tr'));
     }
     afterIF();
    }
function processData(oSettings,arr){
  //process in chuncks of 50;
  // setTimeout takes a long time in IE
  // it'll noticibly slow donw your script when
  // only processing one item at the time
  var tmp=arr.splice(0,50);
  for (var i = 0, len = tmp.length; i < len; i++) {
      _fnAddData(oSettings, tmp[i]);
  }
  if(arr.length!==0){
    setTimeout(function(){
      processData(oSettings,arr);
    },0);
    return;
  }
  afterIf();
}
function afterIf(){
  //continue processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HMR.  You helped to bring me closer to my goal.  To solve the problem I worked my code down to this IIFE:

```
(function processData(oSettings, arr) {

  var tmp = arr.splice(0, 50);

  tickApp.$orders.dataTable().fnAddData(tmp);

  if (arr.length !== 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      processData(oSettings, arr);
    }, 0);
  }
}(oSettings, oInit.aaData.concat()));
```

Instead of using the private _fnAddData function I opted for the DataTables public fnAddData (http://datatables.net/ref#fnAddData) function.  This way I am able to push 50 rows at a time into the table which is stored in the tickApp.$orders object which I just a reference to my jQuery object that stores the table in memory:

```
tickApp.$orders = $('#orders');
```

In another part of my code.  They way you had it it was still pushing 1 row at a time instead of the whole 50.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please note that the fnAddData method has an optional 2nd parameter.  This parameter is whether or not to redraw the table.  The default is true.  So if you call fnAddData 50 times with no 2nd parameter, it will redraw the table 50 times.  This can be very slow for large tables or large inserts.

Comment: Thank you @BumptiousQBangwhistle! I'm wondering ... since I am using DataTables with varying row heights that I am not distinctly setting css values for is it not ideal to redraw the table?  It is going pretty fast like it is but I will change it to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax to fetch your data, you can override "fnServerData" in your datatables config object. This will allow you to fetch the data to be loaded and then process it however you want.

In my case, I have a generic datatables config object that I use for all my datatables. I override the default fnServerData function with one that passes rows to the datatable in sets of 200 using fnAddData and setTimeout to call the function again until all the data has been processed, finally I call fnDraw to draw the table.

```
var DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 200;

function feedDataToDataTableInChunks(startIndex, data, oSettings) {
    var chunk = data.slice(startIndex, DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE);
    oSettings.oInstance.fnAddData(chunk, false);
    if((startIndex += DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE) < data.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            feedDataToDataTableInChunks(startIndex, data, oSettings);
        });
    } else {
        oSettings.oApi._fnInitComplete(oSettings, data);
        oSettings.oInstance.fnDraw();
    }
}

var config = {fnServerData: function(){
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.getJSON(sSource, aoData)
        .done(function (result) {
            feedDataToDataTableInChunks(0, result || [], oSettings);
        });
}}
```

I am using datatables version 1.9.4

Comment: Where do you define the json variable that you pass to _fnInitComplete?

Comment: Sorry, I added a call to fnInitComplete after realizing I forgot to include it, I have updated my answer to use it correctly.